# Failed to get about: googleapi: Error 401: Invalid Credentials, authError

Tags: shell-script, terminal, linux, google-drive-api

Estou usando uma aplicação genérica para Linux do Google Drive, que tem por objetivo fazer Uploads de pastas locais para o Google Drive via Shell Script.

Porém, ao tentar executar comando no terminal do Debian:

> ./gdrive about

a aplicação me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Failed to get about: googleapi: Error 401: Invalid Credentials,
>   authError

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém aqui já usou essa aplicação e/ou saberia me informar qual o possível problema? (Lembrando que já limpei o cache do sistema, reinstalei a aplicação, mas não soluciona)

Link da aplicação no GitHub: https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/

Estou usando esta versão.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente essa pergunta esta fora do escopo do site, mais respondendo, como espera fazer upload sem se autenticar no Drive? Na descrição do projeto tem a seção falando de [Service Account](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/#service-account).

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui Solucionar de uma forma simples. Veja minha resposta abaixo! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema.
Basicamente, o software armazena uma chave da Autenticação do Google Drive no arquivo .json no diretório

```
/home/.gdrive/
/home/.gdrive/file_cache.json
/home/.gdrive/token_v2.json
```

e sempre que solicitarmos um novo `./gdrive`, o software verifica se esse arquivo existe. O problema é que esse arquivo está oculto.

O que eu fiz?
Eu executei o comando:

`locate gdrive`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e encontrei todas as ocorrências do nome no meu sistema.
Depois eu faço:

```
locate gdrive | xargs rm
```

para excluir todas as ocorrências possíveis de gdrive no servidor.

Então, eu faço o novo download:

```
wget https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download
```

mv ucid0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTAexpordownload gdrive

e depois :

```
./gdrive about
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo funciona perfeito neste método